# how to convert xlsx files to simple xls for a given folder

Tags: python

I have a code that is working with xls but not with xlsx. I have more than a 100 files so, i would like to convert all the xlsx to xls. Can you suggest me something to handle it?

Comment: @pistol2myhead I think it's about conversion, not renaming

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "convert all the xlsx to xls"? do you mean a file format conversion or just a file renaming? Furthermore, sharing the code you've done so far could help in answering your question

Comment: I meant conversion, because only renaming doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mass conversion to the older Excel 97-2003:

```
import glob
from win32com.client import Dispatch

for file in glob.glob('/home/adam/*.xlsx'):
    xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(file)
    wb.SaveAs(file[:-1], FileFormat=56)
    xl.Quit()
```

Comment: it says ImportError: No module named win32com.client

Comment: What about installing it? `pip install pypiwin32`